# How do I fix this triangulation issue?

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have this mesh of a ridge that I originally made by simply using the knife tool across a plane. This left me with a very disproportionate amount of vertices in the y-axis.

As I currently understand it, the shading artifacts that I've highlighted below are due to bad topology and ideally I want quads (or triangles) on the top and bottom planes as well.

Is there any tool in blender that can speed this up. I mean, I could walk through each vertex and add the edges by hand, that's not too much work but I was hoping that there's a tool that can actually do this, since what I want here is exactly one additional edge per vertex on the upper and lower plane.

[image: Triangulation issues]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fill the faces with quads or triangles, or remove the smooth shading on the nogons.

You can try (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) then (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), to fill it with quads, as a quick fix.

A better method would be to repair your modeling.

[image]

1. Delete the vertices on the ends of your N-gons:
   [image]
2. Select one of the edge loops at the bottom *or* top.
   [image]
3. Extrude the vertices out(<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X y or Z</kbd>)
   [image]
4. scale them to zero along the axis that you extruded them out(<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X y or Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>).

   [image]
5. Do the same for the bottom vertices.

Comment: That will do, though I was hoping for something to basically connect the vertices from one edge to another.

Comment: See edit my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want vertex normals to blend you can use sharp edges or enable auto-smooth in the mesh normals panel (which works in the view-port with version 2.71).

Answer (score 0):

If these surfaces are planar you might set their shading to flat shading.

Else:

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to automatically triangulate the polygons
- Use the Triangulate modifier to non-destructively triangulate the mesh.
- Select vertex pairs of the polygons and press <kbd>J</kbd> to join/connect them.