# Strange shading on curved surface

Tags: modeling

[image]It is really hard to describe my problem accurately, but I try the best I can. I am using Blender to create meshes for Unreal Engine. However, this problem shows already in Blender. I don´t know the terminology, So I go right ahead and describe shortly what is wrong about the picture attached.
You can see a diagonal shadow cast after I turned on the smooth shading. That does not look very good (I am sorry, that I cannot describe it any better).
You would really help me out if you could explain my mistake to me!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/smooth-shaded-model-has-odd-shading and this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14652/how-do-i-fix-this-triangulation-issue. In short, this is caused by the topology.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18055/strange-lighting-problem-with-normals/18058#18058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have *Smooth* shading enabled in your *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Tools tab > Edit dropdown > Shading:*. There is a way to fix this without going back to *Flat* shading.

Go to the *Properties panel > Object Modifiers tab* and add an *Edge Split* modifier. The default settings should be ok, but if they aren't, you can change the *Split Angle:*, which is defined as the max value at which an angle should be split.

*The Edge Split modifier:*

[image]

*Comparison with a cylinder:*

[image]